# Can't get rid of BluejeansHelper.log

Tags: files, uninstall

I have been trying to do that since April, in vain. I had to install Bluejeans on my laptop to run some tests. Bluejean was not up to the task so I uninstalled it. Since then, there is that  BluejeansHelper.log in my Home directory that I can't trash. I tried Purge among many other commands. Nothing. Any idea (I am on 18.04.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Bluejeans to try this out. It appears that the uninstaller does not remove the log file after the uninstall process.

You can remove the log file using the terminal. Use  ***<Ctrl> + <Alt> + T*** to open a new terminal window.
And run  `rm -f ~/BluejeansHelper.log`

In my case, the file was in my .config folder, so I just had to remove it from there. 
 `rm -f /home/midway/.config/bluejeans-v2/BluejeansHelper.log`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I really appreciate.
It didn't work though. The file comes back each time I restart my computer :(

Comment: @yooy, that is very strange. Can you please run the below and paste the output here?
`dpkg -l | grep -i bluejeans`

Comment: @MidwayNomand, Thanks again... Nothing comes out from it, probably because I uninstalled Bluejeans and tried a lot of things to get rid of that last file (like purge). 
I am wondering if I shouldn't reinstall it and restart the process on uninstall it again.

Comment: @yooy, Can you please check if you are seeing a Bluejeans*.desktop file in this location : `~/.config/autostart/`. `~` is your home directory. Can you delete .desktop file, the log file, restart and see if you are still facing this issue?

Comment: @MidwayNomand It worked ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @yooy, I'm glad it worked!!  :)

Answer (score 9):

Solved by @MidwayNomand ! In brief :
Check if you are seeing a Bluejeans*.desktop file in this location : ~/.config/autostart/. ~ is your home directory.

delete .desktop file, the log file, restart

Comment: this is the correct answer